# Update a TableView Cell UI from observer

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to update the UI of a cell while downloading a file. I have a listener which tracks the progress of the download.

But it seems that I cannot update my UI from the listener, neither `reloaddata()` works nor `layoutifneeded()`

Here is some code:

```
// MARK: - VODownloader Observer

extension DownloadsTableViewControllerPhone : VODownloaderEventListener{
    func onDownloadPrepared(_ downloader: VODownloader!) {
        print("onDownloadPrepared")
    }

    func onDownloadInfoEvent(_ downloader: VODownloader!, info: Int) {

        switch info {
        case VODownloaderInfo.infoDownloadProgress.rawValue:
            print("infoDownloadProgress")

            //Example: Update first cell UI
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DownloadsTableViewCellPhone
            cell?.downloadedVideoDownloadProgressLabel.text =   "Download duration \(downloader.duration) %"

            //Update the UI ???
            cell?.layoutIfNeeded()
            tableView.reloadData()

        case VODownloaderInfo.infoDownloadCompleted.rawValue:
            print("infoDownloadCompleted")
        case VODownloaderInfo.infoKeyoRenewalCompleted.rawValue:
            print("infoKeyoRenewalCompleted")
        case VODownloaderInfo.infoDownloadSpeed.rawValue:
            print("infoDownloadSpeed: \(downloader.currentBitrate)")
        default:
            break
        }


    }

    func onDownloadErrorEvent(_ downloader: VODownloader!, errorCode error: Int) {
        print("onDownloadErrorEvent")

    }

}
```

Comment: check `cell != nil`  then update your UI

Comment: I think this doesn't have to do with the problem that I am currently facing. Still it's good to add it since it's nil when I out-scroll it.

Comment: of course it matter, if your cell is empty than any updation in cell not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [Kamran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395636/kamran) answer, check is UI features performed in the main thread.

Also.

tableView.reloadData() will call cellForRowAtIndexPath,
so you got to update your label text in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

you can try to do so without calling reloadData

```
 case VODownloaderInfo.infoDownloadProgress.rawValue:
        print("infoDownloadProgress")

        //Example: Update first cell UI
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DownloadsTableViewCellPhone
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        cell?.downloadedVideoDownloadProgressLabel.text = "Download duration \(downloader.duration) %"
        tableView.endUpdates()
```

another way to avoid unnecessary reloading of the whole tableView content

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

but anyway, more properly to set data inside the UITableViewDatasource cellForRowAtIndexPath method